# TextView.SetMaxLines padding the text n lines

Tags: android, textview, xamarin.android

I've been trying to create a expandable `TextView` that starts off with 5 lines ( *if the initial text has more than 5 lines* ).

The code I have so far is the following:

```cs
TextView
    textView;
Button
    button;

textView.LayoutChange += delegate {
    if( textView.LineCount > 5 ) {
        button.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        textView.SetMaxLines( 5 );

        button.Click += delegate {
            button.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            textView.SetMaxLines( Int32.MaxValue );
        };
    }
};

textView.Text = "Text that may occupy more than 5 lines due to size.";
```

Basically, I have a `TextView` where I add `delegate` to the `LayoutChange` event. After that, I set the initial text to `textView`. So far so good. The `delegate` is invoked after setting the text and sets the `MaxLines` of the `textView` to `5` if the text spans over the line count limit.

The problem is, when the user clicks on the `button`, the `textView` `MaxLines` is set to `Int32.MaxValue` ( *so far, so good* ) but the text is *padded* 5 lines from the top, cutting the text.

I've tried to set the `MaxLines` to 0 and the to `Int32.MaxValue` and/or setting the text to `""` and then again to the required text, with no results.

Any idea about what's going on, or about what I'm doing wrong here?

---

***EDIT*** Added images to illustrate what's happening. The text seems to be padded the same amount of space that the text initially occupied, with `MaxLines` set.

The left image is the `textView` with `MaxLines` set to `5`, and the right one is the `textView` with `MaxLines` set to `Int32.MaxValue`.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I might have found *a* solution - not **the** solution - for this issue. It might even be a bug on Xamarin - or on Android itself.

Either way, I've found that the `TextView.SetMaxLines( Int32 )` doesn't like sudden changes. So, to make this work without `TextView` getting a padding from nowhere, I had to set a `while`, incrementing the value by 1 before passing the value to the method.

The end result looks like this:

```
TextView
    textView = ...;
Button
    buttonView = ...;
Int32
    lineCount = 0,
    maxLines = 5;

textView.LayoutChange += delegate {
    if( textView.LineCount <= maxLines ) {
        return;
    }

    lineCount = textView.LineCount;

    buttonView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    textView.SetMaxLines( maxLines );

    buttonView.Click += delegate {
        buttonView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        while( maxLines++ <= lineCount ) {
            textView.SetMaxLines( maxLines );
        }
    };
};
```